# How to inject uibModalInstance using $injector.get() while upgrading to bootstrap version 2.3.0

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am upgrading the existing modules/directives those are using bootstrap (ver 0.11.0 ) to use bootstrap **2.3.0.** I also need backward compatibility to support version 0.11.0 as well, because this directive can be used at other places where we are using 0.11.0.

The directive has been using `$modal` and `$modalInstance`, which are now `$uibModal` and `$uibModalInstance` respectively with version 2.3.0.

I am using following approach, for conditionally injecting `$uibModal` and `$uibModalInstance` in the module:

```
 if ($injector.has('$modalInstance')) {
        $modalInstance = $injector.get('$modalInstance');
    } else {
        $modalInstance = $injector.get('$uibModalInstance');
    }
```

The approach is working for **`$uibModal`** but **not** for **`$uibModalInstance`**. It is because the provider for `modalInstance` are not defined. Thus, end up as following Error:

> Unknown provider: `$uibModalInstanceProvider` <- `$uibModalInstance`

Is there someway I can chose between `$modalInstance` or `$uibModalInstance` at runtime and inject the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's long time and I would like to update how we solved that back then.

We are not injecting either $uibModalInstance or $modalInstance. Instead, using $injector to identify at runtime:

```
 if ($injector.has('$modal')) {
              $modal = $injector.get('$modal');
          } else {
              $modal = $injector.get('$uibModal');
          }
```

This solved our purpose.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can continue using `$modalInstance` in code. Just while mapping the injections, you need to have `$uibModalInstance` pointing to `$modalInstance`. Same applies for `$uibModal` and `$modal`.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('modalCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance',
    function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

        $modalInstance.doSomething = function(param) {
           ...
        }

        ...
```

Similarly, you can have that for `$injector` syntax (since you seem to use it)

Comment: We map injections while writting JS code. I need to determine at runtime, if we have $modalInstance or $uibModalInstance.

Comment: @Ciphersumeet didn't get you. can you share more of your code in question?

Comment: I actually don't want to inject the $uibModalInstance, while defining controller. because the same Controller need to work with $modal Instance for one page but with $uibModalInstance for other page. That's because difference pages may have different version of bootstrap. Thus inside the Controller I wan't fetch the modalInstance using $injector.get method instead of passing it into controller.

Comment: @Ciphersumeet hard to say what's going wrong then.. maybe you can pull out a plunker reproducing issue? also, why not just upgrade version for all modules/pages.. you can still use `$modal` as I mentioned in answer..